# grails gsp refresh model over a set interval

Tags: jquery, grails, setinterval, gsp

I'm trying to refresh/get the latest domain model via my GSP without having to refresh the page. This is to help with a loading screen I'm displaying.

Provided I have another background application updating the "name" of my foo domain behind the scenes. Should the following code print out the new names as they come in every 5 seconds?

```
setInterval(function() {
    <g:set var="check" value="${foo.refresh()}">
    console.log("${check.name}");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the server side code (Groovy taglib) with the client side code (JS)... This can't possibly work.

Comment: so ill need to go ahead and use ajax to get server side to refresh/send me latest name. thks